# Reading variables from a configuration file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to determine the best way to read in a configuration file. This "Parameters.cfg" file is just to define values and is of this form:

```
origin_uniform_distribution 0
origin_defined 1
angles_gaussian 0
angles_uniform_distribution 0
angles_defined 0
startx 0
starty 0
gap 500
nevents 1000
origin_uniform_distribution_x_min -5
origin_uniform_distribution_x_max 5
origin_uniform_distribution_y_min -5
origin_uniform_distribution_y_max 5
origin_defined_x 0
origin_defined_y 0
angles_gaussian_center 0
angles_gaussian_sigma 5
angles_uniform_distribution_x_min -5
angles_uniform_distribution_x_max 5
angles_uniform_distribution_y_min -5
angles_uniform_distribution_y_max 5
angles_defined_x 10
angles_defined_y 10
```

The names are there for the user to know which variables they are defining. I would like to have my program read in only the actual numbers and skip over the strings. I know I can do this in a way where I define a whole lot of strings in my program, and then just leave them sitting there defined but obviously unused. Is there a way to read in the numbers easily while skipping over the strings?

Comment: No point re-inventing the wheel: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libini/ or http://sourceforge.net/projects/libconfig/

Comment: Is this an existing config file that you're working with, or can you redesign the config file?

Comment: It can be redesigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method doesn't store the string *at all* (like was asked for in the question):

```
static const std::streamsize max = std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max();
std::vector<int> values;
int value;

while(file.ignore(max, ' ') >> file >> value)
{
    values.push_back(value);
}
```

It uses [ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) instead of reading the string and not using it.

Comment: +1 for doing exactly what the question said, but I think the code is less clear than the alternative of using a temporary string variable.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with the obvious solution?

```
string param_name;
int param_value;

while ( fin >> param_name >> param_value )
{
  ..
}
```

You can discard the `param_name` after each iteration while storing the `param_value` wherever you need it.

Answer (score 3):

When you read out the strings, just don't store them anywhere:

```
std::vector<int> values;
std::string discard;
int value;
while (file >> discard >> value) {
  values.push_back(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess I must be overdue to post a ctype facet to ignore the strings and read only the data we care about:

```
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct number_only: std::ctype<char> { 
    number_only() : std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {} 

    static mask const *get_table() { 
        static std::vector<mask> rc(table_size, space);

        std::fill_n(&rc['0'], 10, digit);
        rc['-'] = punct;
        return &rc[0]; 
    } 
};

int main() { 
    // open the file
    std::ifstream x("config.txt");

    // have the file use our ctype facet:
    x.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new number_only));

    // initialize vector from the numbers in the file:
    std::vector<int> numbers((std::istream_iterator<int>(x)), 
                              std::istream_iterator<int>());

    // display what we read:
    std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

This way the extraneous data is really and truly ignored -- after imbuing the stream with our facet, it's as if the strings don't exist at all.

Comment: This encapsulates the behaviour, giving it a name, and is re-usable, whereas the accepted solution needs to be repeated every time you want to do it, and has to be read to be understood. Also, this works with any container constructor or iterator algorithms. Far better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a structure and then overload the `istream` `operator>>` for it:

```
struct ParameterDiscardingName {
    int value;
    operator int() const {
        return value;
    }
};
istream& operator>>(istream& is, ParameterDiscardingName& param) {
    std::string discard;
    return is >> discard >> param.value;
}

ifstream file("Parameters.cfg");
istream_iterator<ParameterDiscardingName> begin(file), end;
vector<int> parameters(begin, end);
```